# Android- Destroy media player service when click on item in Listview

Tags: android, service, media-player, android-listview, ondestroy

I currently have a `listview` and when you click on an item it runs a `service` with a `mediaplayer`. If I click on another item in the `listview` the `service` that's running should stop and run the new `service`. What would be the best way of handling this? Would it be to use the `onDestroy`? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you ask me you should not stop and restart service like this but i don't know the exact situation as may be its the necessity of your app.

You should call `context.stopService(yourServiceIntent)` in your ListView's `onItemClick()` then restart the service with new input using `putExtra()` in the same `onItemClick()`.

But i still recommend you to find an alternative to this service stop and restart procedure as it could affect the performance of your app by decreasing the response time.

Comment: So I tried your suggestion and the problem now is that if the service is not running then the application will ANR. Is there a way to detect if the service is running and if it is then stop it?

Comment: @SergioRa yes you can set a flag to true when start the service and set it to false when you stop the service and before restarting it check if the flag is set to true then do not restart it and if it is false then call startService() method. I know flag is a confused keyword for some people. Here by flag i mean declare a simple variable of boolean type for example
`boolean isServiceRunning` and initially set it to false and then change it's value as per your service status.

Comment: No problem my friend. We all are here to help each other. cheers!!

Comment: So I added the flags but I'm not sure If i am doing it correctly. I made another question so here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6725937/android-listview-service-mediaplayer-and-boolean-flags